# On Laravel API I cannot access the $_GET variables in the url at all

Tags: php, laravel

**Here is my api:**

```
Route::get('/search','App\Http\Controllers\GroupsController@search_groups');
```

I have tried 3 methods to dump and die the query string which is in the parameter as `/search?q=some-string`

**My Controller (method 1):**

```
public function search_groups(Request $request)
{        
   $search = !empty($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : null;
   dd($search) //returns null
}
```

**My Controller (method 2):**

```
public function search_groups(Request $request)
{        
   $search = $request->input('q');
   dd($search) //returns null
}
```

**My Controller (method 3):**

```
public function search_groups(Request $request)
{        
   $search = $request->query();
   $search = $search['q'] ?? null;
   dd($search) //returns []
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try this, maybe it helps `$search = $request->query ?? 'not found';`, what you get?

Comment: if you get `q` on `$request->all()` then you should be able to get that using `$request->input`, `$request->get` etc. methods.

Comment: I think problem in your server settings (apache or nginx). Your server should rewrite all parameters to public/index.php

Comment: @coding-scripting I think you are onto something, can you tell me what I should do to the .htaccess?

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi That returns `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#51
  #parameters: []
}`

Comment: @Eddsters You can see what should be in .htaccess [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess). But I think .htaccess is not the whole problem, is your server apache, nginx or something else?